# how to split the grid header using ASP.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

First one is  my existing Grid View ,but i want to split the  grid view Header look like an below the second grid view image.

[image]

and here is my code that processes that output:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" Font-Size="12px" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvSubClaims_RowDataBound" SkinID="GridView1" Width="100%">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SubClaim#">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblSubCliamNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubClaimNo")  %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Features">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblFeatures" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Features") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
       <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Reverse">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblPolCoverage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PolicyCoverage") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Paid ($)">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDamages" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Damage") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recovery ($)">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubClaimStatus") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
       <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Outstanding ($)">
       <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubClaimStatus") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
       </div>
```

What can I change/add to achieve the desired result?

Somebody please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by creating multiple row in group header.

You will find more about [Add Grouped / Multiple row Header in the GridView](http://dotnetarmy.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/add-grouped-multiple-row-header-in.html).

Also there is a good article but in vb about [Create Multiple row / group header in gridview ASP.NET](http://redsouljaz.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/create-multiple-row-group-header-in-gridview-asp-net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Repeater instead of the GridView, you can get more control over how it renders out to HTML e.g.

```
<asp:repeater ... >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
            </th>
            <th colspan="4">
                Expense
            </th>
            <th colspan="4">
                Indemnity
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                SubClaim
            </th>
            <th>
                Feature
            </th>
            <th>
                Current<br/>Reserve<br/>($)
            </th>
            ...
         </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubCliamNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubClaimNo")  %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
             <asp:Label ID="lblFeatures" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Features") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```